# Confused about std.xml - how do I read attributes?

Tags: xml, parsing, d

I've just thrown together an XML control file for a command-line tool I'm writing to manage my compilers. My goal is to basically use this XML file to take a statement like `compile d -release foo.d` made at the shell, process it to form `dmd -m64 -O -inline -release -noboundscheck foo.d` and execute it. I've reproduced the XML file here for clarity:

```
<compilers>
<compiler id="d">
    <command>"dmd -m64"</command>
    <modes>
        <mode id="-debug">"-debug -unittest -w -de"</mode>
        <mode id="-release">"-O -inline -release -noboundscheck"</mode>
    </modes>
</compiler>
<compiler id="java">
    <command>"javac"</command>
    <modes>
        <mode id="-debug">"-g -Xlint"</mode>
    </modes>
</compiler>
```

Now, from my reading of `std.xml`, I have to do something like this:

```
import std.xml, std.stdio, std.string, std.file;

void main(string[] args) {
    auto from_command_line = someFunctionThatDealsWithInput(args);
    string s = cast(string)std.file.read("path/to/xml/file.xml");
    check(s);
    auto parsed = DocumentParser(s);
    //deal with the XML somehow to construct a valid command line command
    //send it to the shell
 }
```

I know how to execute stuff at the shell, but I'm not sure how to make use of the XML document using the `std.xml` API. In particular, I'm unclear how to get at the content of a node's attributes (but to be honest, the whole thing doesn't make a lot of sense to me).

Comment: Note that `std.xml` is deprecated.

Comment: @Cubic: From the Phobos documentation page:
"Warning: This module is considered out-dated and not up to Phobos' current standards. It will remain until we have a suitable replacement, but be aware that it will not remain long term."

That isn't _quite_ deprecated yet - they don't seem to have a replacement for it.

Comment: It's not quite deprecated in the sense of "Replace that with this instead", but it is in the sense of "please don't start any new projects with this, it's kinda bad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest KXML instead (https://github.com/opticron/kxml)? I find it very easy to parse XML with it (especially with builtin XPath requests).

Comment: yeah, or my dom.d if you are used to using javascript's api. (only need the files dom.d and characterencodings.d) https://github.com/adamdruppe/misc-stuff-including-D-programming-language-web-stuff the job here could be done easily with querySelector or getElementById and then the property innerText to get the command line.